# How to see if an object is an array without using reflection?

Tags: java, arrays, gwt, instanceof

How can I see in Java if an Object is an array without using reflection?
And how can I iterate through all items without using reflection?

I use Google GWT so I am not allowed to use reflection :(

I would love to implement the following methods without using refelection:

```
private boolean isArray(final Object obj) {
  //??..
}

private String toString(final Object arrayObject) {
  //??..
}
```

BTW: neither do I want to use JavaScript such that I can use it in non-GWT environments.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You can use `Class.isArray()`

```
public static boolean isArray(Object obj)
{
    return obj!=null && obj.getClass().isArray();
}
```

This works for both object and primitive type arrays.

For toString take a look at `Arrays.toString`. You'll have to check the array type and call the appropriate `toString` method.

Comment: Worth adding that you can find out the array type by using `obj.getClass().getComponentType()`.

Answer (score 74):

You can use `instanceof`.

#### [JLS 15.20.2 Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2)

> ```
>  RelationalExpression:
>     RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
> ```
>
> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not `null` and the reference could be cast to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.

That means you can do something like this:

```
Object o = new int[] { 1,2 };
System.out.println(o instanceof int[]); // prints "true"
```

You'd have to check if the object is an `instanceof boolean[]`, `byte[]`, `short[]`, `char[]`, `int[]`, `long[]`, `float[]`, `double[]`, or `Object[]`, if you want to detect all array types.

Also, an `int[][]` is an `instanceof Object[]`, so depending on how you want to handle nested arrays, it can get complicated.

For the `toString`, [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has a `toString(int[])` and other overloads you can use. It also has `deepToString(Object[])` for nested arrays.

```
public String toString(Object arr) {
   if (arr instanceof int[]) {
      return Arrays.toString((int[]) arr);
   } else //...
}
```

It's going to be very repetitive (but even [`java.util.Arrays` is very repetitive](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#av_p04Hv9fs/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java&l=478)), but that's the way it is in Java with arrays.

#### See also

- [Managing highly repetitive code and documentation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337170/managing-highly-repetitive-code-and-documentation-in-java)
- [Java Arrays.equals() returns false for two dimensional arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721033/java-arrays-equals-returns-false-for-two-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Thanks, it didn't realize it's that simple. Thought insstanceof couldn't be used straightforward with T[] :(

Comment: BTW: I also noticed another nice way to discover if something is an array
Class.isArray() (used in the Arrays.deepToString()).

Comment: @edbras: yes, that's what Steve Kuo was saying down below. My solution uses pure linguistic construct instead of API call.

Comment: It works fine, I only don't use instanceof but getClass as comparision.
Something like:
if (array.getClass == int[].class) {
  Arrays.toString((int[]) array);
}
Thanks all..

Comment: @edbras: That's how `java.util.Arrays` does it, yes. I see that you've been reading the code I linked to.

Comment: I prefer Steve Kuo's answer. This answer is not general, you need to know the type of array (example : int) however the other answer is generic.

Answer (score 42):

One can access each element of an array separately using the following code:

```
Object o=...;
if ( o.getClass().isArray() ) {
    for(int i=0; i<Array.getLength(o); i++){
        System.out.println(Array.get(o, i));
    }
}
```

Notice that it is unnecessary to know what kind of underlying array it is, as this will work for any array.

Comment: `isArray()` was already adequately covered in the answers posted 4 years prior to this one.

Comment: This answer is great because it shows us how to get the size of an array and retrieve an element without knowledge of its content type. I'm sure most people have never written code like this before.

Answer (score 11):

There is no subtyping relationship between arrays of primitive type, or between an array of a primitive type and array of a reference type.  See [JLS 4.10.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.3).

Therefore, the following is incorrect as a test to see if `obj` is an array *of any kind*:

```
// INCORRECT!
public boolean isArray(final Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Object[];
}
```

Specifically, it doesn't work if `obj` is 1-D array of primitives.  (It does work for primitive arrays with higher dimensions though, because all array types are subtypes of `Object`.  But it is moot in this case.)

> I use Google GWT so I am not allowed to use reflection :(

The best solution (to the `isArray` array part of the question) depends on what counts as "using reflection".

- In GWT, calling `obj.getClass().isArray()` does not count as using reflection<sup>1</sup>, so that is the best solution.
- Otherwise, the best way of figuring out whether an object has an array type is to use a sequence of `instanceof` expressions.

  ```
  public boolean isArray(final Object obj) {
      return obj instanceof Object[] || obj instanceof boolean[] ||
         obj instanceof byte[] || obj instanceof short[] ||
         obj instanceof char[] || obj instanceof int[] ||
         obj instanceof long[] || obj instanceof float[] ||
         obj instanceof double[];
  }
  ```
- You could also try messing around with the name of the object's class as follows, but the call to `obj.getClass()` is bordering on reflection.

  ```
  public boolean isArray(final Object obj) {
      return obj.getClass().toString().charAt(0) == '[';
  }
  ```

---

<sup>1 - More precisely, the `Class.isArray` method is listed as supported by GWT in [this page](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can create a utility class to check if the class represents any **Collection**, **Map** or **Array**

```
  public static boolean isCollection(Class<?> rawPropertyType) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(rawPropertyType) || 
               Map.class.isAssignableFrom(rawPropertyType) || 
               rawPropertyType.isArray();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `obj instanceof Object[]` (tested on JShell).