# Total amount of elements in two dimensional array

Tags: java, java-7

Recently we learned two dimensional arrays and solved task of calculating average of all elements in it. My code was like:

```
int a[][] = {
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
  {6, 4, 2, 7},
  {3, 6},
  {2, 6, 8},
};

int sum=0, amount=0;
for (int[] row : a)
  for (int val : row) {
    sum += val; amount += 1;
  }

return sum / (double) amount;
```

The thing is that I don't like the way I calculated the amount of elements in array.
I tried to use **size()**, it not worked, tried to use Array and Arrays classes but both can retrieve neither amount of rows nor amount of elements in some row, just as a **.length** property.

**Question:** is there **any way** of retrieving the amount of elements from two or more dimensional matrices without using loops?

Comment: Since each array in the first array may have different sizes, I think you need a loop here.

Comment: I think the coda is very laconic.

Comment: Thought maybe I missed something while learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no native Java functionality for this, as an array of arrays (of arrays (of arrays ...)) is not a language construct per se. Array is, but an array of arrays is just an array of Objects (which again may, but need not be arrays). The notation `Object[][]` just provides type-safety for multi-dimensional arrays.

There is no way you can calculate this without looping,  but you can solve it using reflection and recursion for arrays of arbitrary dimensions.

---

A generic solution, where performance is not an issue, that counts all non-array elements for arbitrary dimensional arrays using recursion and [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) could look something like this:

```
public static int size(Object object) {
    if (!object.getClass().isArray()) {
        return 1;
    }

    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(object); i++) {
        size += size(Array.get(object, i));
    }
    return size;
}
```

You can call this function with any object:

```
int[][] matrix = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};


Object[] array = {
    "1",
    new String[]{
        "2", "3", "4"
    },
    new int[][] {
        { 5 },
        { 6, 7 },
        { 8, 9, 10 }
    }
};


String literal = "literal";

System.out.println(size(matrix));
System.out.println(size(array));
System.out.println(size(literal));
```

would then output

```
9
10
1
```

It's not a very elegant solution, but as [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725555/804840) puts it:

> It's going to be very repetitive (but even `java.util.Arrays` is very repetitive), but that's the way it is in Java with arrays.

Comment: Yes, that's a good one, to look through dimensions recursively, I will remember that, thanks. Also, I searched other ways for these two days and didn't found any, but understand why it is not worthy to implement such methods in the case of java.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There's not really a concept of a 2d array in Java (C# has it though) - what you have there is actually an array of arrays. And since each "internal" array can have a different length, it's hard to do without a loop.

Is the loop really an issue, or are you just looking for a more "built-in" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Find out how many elemnts are in the Array.

```
public class MultiArrayEx3 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        int[][] myNumbers = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9} };
        int x = myNumbers[0].length;
        int y = myNumbers[1].length;
        int z = x + y;

        System.out.println(z);

    }
}
```

Comment: ...and what if the input array has only 1 array? Or 20?