# Java best practice: set System.out.println() on other method

Tags: java, system.out

I would like to map `System.out.println` on another function, such as:

```
public static void puts(Object o) { System.out.printl(o); }
```

This goes against some Java best-practice, or can have any drawbacks I did not think about?

Comment: Is this just because `System.out.println` is so damn wordy, or do you have another reason?

Comment: Other than boxing, I see no issues.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would like to create such method? If you want to reduce `System.out.println` you remove `System` by static import of `System.out`.

Comment: If declared within a class, it can be used in conjunction with something like `private static final String _CLASS_NAME = MyClass.class.getName()`, for logging purpose (id est, the `puts` method could do `System.out.println(_CLASS_NAME + ": " + o)`).

Comment: Got it. It is useless, but still, it does not seem to be wrong (even if these two are quite similar).

Comment: I think if you're referring directly to `System.out` in so many places that it's become cumbersome, *that* is what's against Java best practice. Classes/methods should generally have a output stream given to them, not just grab a static reference to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you want. When you call the method, it will work the same as `System.out.println`, in most cases.

The problem is if you try this:

```
puts(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
```

If you do that with `System.out.println`, you will get `hello`. But if you do it with `puts`, you get something like this:

```
[C@812f71
```

If you don't print `char[]`s, you will be just fine.

Comment: Is there an overall way to say `new int[] { 1, 2 } instanceof int[]` for arrays in general?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725533/how-to-see-if-an-object-is-an-array-without-using-reflection check with that and use `Arrays.toString()`