# How to correct this simple Java code? [How to print all elements of a variable with apprarent type = Object and actual type = int (array)?]

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String s = new String("abc");
        int [] a = {1,2,3,4};
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(a[1]);
        Object o1 = s;
        Object o2 = a;
        System.out.println(o1);
        System.out.println(o2[2]);

     }
}
```

I am geeting the following error after compiling and executing the aforementioned code on the website http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php :

```
Compiling the source code....
$javac HelloWorld.java 2>&1

HelloWorld.java:12: error: array required, but Object found
        System.out.println(o2[2]);
                             ^
1 error
```

How do I print each element of the array saved in the object o2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, every array is also an `Object`.

But *every* non-primitive value is an `Object`, so clearly not every `Object` is an array. It could be a `String`, an `Integer`, an object of your own class, etc. The compiler doesn't know about this at compile time: it only becomes clear at runtime what the actual type of the `Object` is.

You can check if your object is an array using `instanceof` and you can cast it to an array type:

```
if (o2 instanceof int[]) {
    int[] myarray = (int[])o2;
    System.out.println(myarray[2]);
}
```

But you *need* to cast it before you can use it as an array, it's not optional.

Comment: Your answer states the correct reason why `o2[2]` not allowed and uses `instance of`.(+1)

Comment: ...and it shows how to check for an int[] before the cast (+1)

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast it to `int array` first and print the index of it.

**sample:**

```
System.out.println(((int[])o2)[2]);
```

**result:**

```
3
```

Comment: You don't need to "print the index of it" (which your code snippet doesn't anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution use following code:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String s = new String("abc");
    int [] a = {1,2,3,4};
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(a[1]);
    Object o1 = s;
    Object o2 = a;
    System.out.println(o1);
    System.out.println(((int[])o2)[2]);

 }
```

}

**Output**

```
Hello World
abc
2
abc
3
```

**Cause:**
When you assign a array to object, for traversing you need to cast it back to array and than get the values

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper method to print the Object. This method will check the type and print the object accordingly. Like:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String s = new String("abc");
        int [] a = {1,2,3,4};
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(a[1]);
        Object o1 = s;
        Object o2 = a;
        printObject(o1);
        printObject(o2);
    }

    private static void printObject(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof String) {
            System.out.println(object);
        } else if (object instanceof int[]) {
            for (int element : (int []) object) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
        // Add other datatype checks
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
Hello World
abc
2
abc
1
2
3
4
```

As you want to print all the elements of the object, this method do the same.

You can also check the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725555/2421561) to know about object type verification.