# Camera2 getCameraCharacteristics Returning Problematic Values

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have a problem with a code snippet that I added to the end of the createCameraPreviewSession function of the Camera2Basic example code.

I have the following snippet that prints the camera characteristics to the console:

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
List<CameraCharacteristics.Key<?>> keys = characteristics.getKeys();
for (CameraCharacteristics.Key key: keys){
    //Log.i(key.getName(), (String)characteristics.get(key));
    //Log.i("hello", "there");
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + "- " + key.getName() + "; Value: " + characteristics.get(key));
}
```

and for the most part it returns good values:

```
Key: android.sensor.info.pixelArraySize; Value: 4128x3096
```

But for many values the result is neither reasonable nor null, but appears to have some encoding issue:

```
Key: android.control.aeAvailableModes; Value: [I@829b672
```

I've tried testing for and omitting null values and re-casting to String.
Ideally I need to print out the full set of values legibly, or test whether the value is relevant rather than getting garbage values in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES) entry is an integer array (int[]).  If you call toString on it, you get the default Java output for an array's toString() call.  See [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) for details of that.

You can use Arrays.toString() instead to get the output you likely want ("[1,3,5,3]" I assume), but you'll have to hard-code which keys to use it on.

Comment: It is not necessary to hard-code the keys that return arrays: a simple check [is available in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725855/192373).