# Performance impact of autoboxing

Tags: java, performance, autoboxing

Usually the compiler generates code to perform boxing and unboxing. But what does the compiler, if the boxed values are not needed? Is the (Oracle standard) compiler smart enough to optimize it away?

Take a look at this method:

```
public static void requireInRange(int index, Object[] array) {
    if(index < 0 || index >= array.length)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

The only relevant information is the `array.length`, so it would be useless to box each value of an array for example. Like in this code:

```
int[] anArray = {3, 4, 2};
requireInRange(3, anArray);
```

Will the compiler actually insert code for boxing each value of the array?

Comment: In general with Java, do not worry about premature optimization.  Write your code so that it is easy to read/understand/modify/etc and let Hotspot or $otherJVM take care of runtime optimizations.  If things are slow, profile to figure out why and then optimize.  (comment instead of answer this isn't a direct answer to your question)

Comment: There is no auto boxing here. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no autoboxing in your code. In fact, given:

```
public static void requireInRange(int index, Object[] array) {
   ...
}

int[] anArray = {3, 4, 2};
requireInRange(3, anArray); // DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
```

While an `int` can be autoboxed to an `Integer`, an `int[]` does *NOT* get autoboxed to `Integer[]` by Java. You can write library functions to do this, but the language will not facilitate this conversion.

This is in fact the source of many confusion regarding e.g. `Arrays.asList(anIntArray)` being "broken", because instead of returning a `List<Integer>`, what is returned is in fact a one-element `List<int[]>`.

---

#### But what about performance???

A quote from [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html):

> It is not appropriate to use autoboxing and unboxing for scientific computing, or other performance-sensitive numerical code. An `Integer` is not a substitute for an `int`; autoboxing and unboxing blur the distinction between primitive types and reference types, but they do not eliminate it.

In short, whenever autoboxing happens, performance definitely takes a little bit of a hit. Certain things help to alleviate this, e.g. the caching mechanism built into these types. This is why you get the following:

```
    System.out.println(
        ((Integer) 0) == ((Integer) 0)
    );
    // true

    System.out.println(
        ((Integer) 10000) == ((Integer) 10000)
    );
    // false (implementation-specific)
```

What happened here is that when `0` is *automatically* boxed, no *new* `Integer` instance is actually created: values in certain range is *cached* for autoboxing purposes, to help performance. `10000` in most implementation probably falls out of this range, but some JVM implementations do allow you to specify the cache range if necessary.

---

#### But I just want to get the length of the array!!!

There are many ways to facilitate your `requireInRange` to work with any type of arrays. Unfortunately working with Java's array of primitives often times mean lots of repetition. This mean providing overloads for `int[]`, `boolean[]`, `byte[]`, `Object[]`, etc separately.

A more concise option is to use reflection, but this has its pluses and minuses. Generally speaking, reflection should not be the preferred solution for most scenarios.

Having said that, [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) does have a [`int getLength(Object array)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength%28java.lang.Object%29) `static` method that can return the length of *ANY* array. It's not typesafe (like most reflection mechanism are); passing a non-array compiles, but throws `IllegalArgumentException` at run-time.

#### Related questions

- [Managing highly repetitive code and documentation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337170/managing-highly-repetitive-code-and-documentation-in-java) - ("inspired" by [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html))

Answer (score 5):

> Will the compiler actually insert code
>   for boxing each value of the array?

The compiler will reject the code because an `int[]` cannot be passed into a method that takes an `Object[]` parameter.

Autoboxing happens only for individual primitive values, never for entire arrays.

Answer (score 4):

If in doubt, you can assume the compiler does not optimize the code. Generally, it does a literal translation of the code.

Additionally, if in doubt, you can assume the JVM does a very good job of optimizing the code at runtime. I wouldn't assume it makes any difference unless you have a good reason (such as profiler) to suspect it is a problem.