# Most concise way to insert array of bytes into List<Byte>?

Tags: java, list

In some code I'm creating a List of Bytes, and want to insert an array of bytes into the list as I am building it.  What is the cleanest way of doing this?  See code below - thanks.

```
public class ListInsert {
    public static byte[] getData() {
        return new byte[]{0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        list.add((byte)0xaa);
        list.add(getData()); // I want to insert an array of bytes into the list here
        list.add((byte)0x55);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answers below, but I'm intrigued what you're going to do with your list of bytes...

Comment: It's for a device I'm working with, need to send certain message packets out the serial port.

Comment: Using a List<Byte> is a really inefficient way to deal with serial coms.  You should write your own list-like wrapper around a byte array, or use byte buffers from java.nio.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*IF* you have a `Byte[] arr` -- an array of reference types -- you can use `Arrays.asList(arr)` to get a `List<Byte>`.

*IF* you have a `byte[] arr` -- an array of primitives -- you can't use `Arrays.asList(arr)` to get a `List<Byte>`. Instead you'll get a one-element `List<byte[]>`.

> That is, while a `byte` can be boxed to a `Byte`, a `byte[]` *DOES NOT* get autoboxed to `Byte[]`!
>   <sub>(also true for other primitives)</sub>

So you have two choices:

- Just iterate over each `byte` in `byte[]` and `add` individually
- Use libraries

  - With [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), you can convert `byte[]` to `Byte[]`

    - You can *then* `Arrays.asList` and `addAll`
  - With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) can convert `byte[]` immediatelly to `List<Byte>`

The first option looks like this:

```
byte[] arr = ...;
for (byte b : arr) {
    list.add(b);
}
```

The second option with Guava looks like this:

```
// requires Guava
byte[] arr = ...;
list.addAll(Bytes.asList(arr));
```

This uses [`Bytes.asList`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#asList%28byte...%29) from [`package com.google.common.primitives`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/package-summary.html). The package has other conversion utilities for other primitives too. The entire library is highly useful.

With Apache Commons Lang, you can use [`Byte[] toObject(byte[])`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28byte[]%29) from `ArrayUtils`:

```
// requires Apache Commons Lang
byte[] arr = ...;
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(arr)));
```

#### Related questions

- [How to convert `int[]` into `List<Integer>` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)
- [`Arrays.asList()` not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)
- [Performance impact of autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430671/performance-impact-of-autoboxing/)
- [Most useful free third party Java libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries)

Comment: Thank you, I had not looked at the google primitives package before, will check it out now.

Answer (score 4):

This might not answer your question but it should be a good practice. If you are heavily manipulating an array of bytes, use the ByteBuffer instead. This class have many types of implementation which can give you the best performance & memory usage. One of them is the Direct ByteBuffer which some operations can run natively.

To put a byte or an array of bytes is as simple as eating a candy:

```
ByteBuffer.put(byte src);
ByteBuffer.put(byte[] src);
ByteBuffer.put(byte[] src, int offset, int length);
```

And the best thing is when you trying to get the bytes out: directly, no array copy's needed (you need to check the size though) :)

```
byte[] data = ByteBuffer.array();
```

Hope you change your mind :)

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(java.lang.Object[])) method which exactly do that:

```
Arrays.asList(getData());
```

So in your case :

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(getData()));
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `byte[]`. `Arrays.asList` doesn't "work" with array of primitives.

Comment: I thought that autoboxing would handle that, but I guess not for arrays then

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `List<Byte>`? I also thought so, but changed my mind. `ByteArrayOutputStream` was much better for me.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// fill in buf or get a single byte b
bo.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
bo.write(b);
byte[] resultArray = bo.toByteArray();
```