# converting an array of bytes to List<Byte>

Tags: java, data-structures

I could think of these things,

1. `Arrays.asList(byte[])` converts `byte[]` to `List<byte[]>`,
2. looping through byte array and add each element to list

I was just wondering Is there any library function to do that?

Comment: Is `Arrays.asList` not a "library function"?

Comment: @vitaut: The point is that Arrays.asList does the wrong thing here.

Comment: there was some problem in my formatting, it converts it to List<byte[]> and not List<Byte>

Comment: IMHO byte[] is typically used for low level data transfer e.g. to disk/network. In such code you would never use List<Byte> as it uses alot more memory and doesn't provide useful functionality for these tasks. List<Byte> may be useful for you, but its not a common usecase.

Comment: late comment but i think this point was missed out . java.util.Arrays.asList(T... a) , here **T... a** is not same as **byte[] or Byte[]** , so any array say **T[]** would be treated as a **single value of type T[]** and **not** as **multiple values of type T**

Comment: Think about using `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `List<Byte>`. An example: [Most concise way to insert array of bytes into List<Byte>?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44744554/772981)

Comment: It's remarkably _stupid_ that there's no easy way to get the result of `String.getBytes()` (a `byte[]`) as a collection or stream.  Would it have killed them to have provided a `ByteStream` class next to `{Int,Long,Double}Stream`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `Byte[]` instead of `byte[]` this would work:

```
  Byte[] array = ....
  List<Byte> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: cannot convert from List<byte[]> to List<Byte>

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It only works with Byte[]. I modified the answer.

Comment: ohh k.. that's interesting... now can i convert byte[] to Byte[]?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java

Comment: This solution assumes that your array is of **object Byte**, not primitive **byte**!

Answer (score 20):

Library [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has ArrayUtils.toObject, which turns a primitive array to a typed object array:

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));
```

Comment: For this answer above : if bytes is an arrays of byte (byte[] bytes), you can do this following :

`List<Byte> byteList = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(bytes));`

Answer (score 19):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771432/1218058) post suggests: the [guava Bytes class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html) can help out:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
List<Byte> byteList = Bytes.asList(bytes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 one-line `byte[]` to `List<Byte>` conversion, given `array` as input:

```
List<Byte> list = IntStream.range(0, array.length).mapToObj(i -> array[i]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest pure Java way, without additional libraries, is this:

```
private static List<Byte> convertBytesToList(byte[] bytes) {
    final List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        list.add(b);
    }
    return list;
}
```

But better check twice if you really need to convert from `byte`to `Byte`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java contains some interesting Java 8 ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] byteArray;
List<Byte> medianList=new ArrayList<>(); 
int median=0,count=0;
Path file=Paths.get("velocities.txt");
if(Files.exists(file)){
    byteArray=Files.readAllBytes(file);
}
medianList.addAll(Arrays.asList(byteArray));
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because you've declared the list with Byte and you are trying to add byte.