# Is casting long to int cheaper than autoboxing long to Long?

Tags: java, android, casting, autoboxing

I have a bunch of `Thingy` objects that I'm keeping track of using `long` ID numbers.  Since I have no guarantees about ID sequence, I'm keeping them in a `HashMap<Long, Thingy>` for random access.  However, in Android, they have this very nice class called [`SparseArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) which they claim is faster than my `HashMap` for how I'm using it.  Perhaps most notably, it doesn't have the autoboxing tax.  Unfortunately, the keys are `int`, not `long`.

The values of my `long` IDs are such that I'm not worried about overflowing the range of `int` anytime this century.  Is that casting from `long` to `int` plus `SparseArray` optimizations are going to be cheaper than autoboxing `long` to `Long` for my `HashMap` operations?  My intuition says yes, but I'd like some additional input.

Comment: This had been asked here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430671/performance-impact-of-autoboxing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um.  Casting `long` to `int` will probably be faster, yes, but it's not clear whether or not it will be *correct*.

Comment: The correctness thing is unlikely rear its head, but I'm certainly aware of the possibility.  Changing the ID type will impact a lot of places, though.  Bleh.  I guess I'll leave it alone for now.  It works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Casting `long` to `int` will be definitely faster, as it is just one JVM command (l2i) opposing to memory allocation and new object creation when using boxing, but, as Louis pointed, you are losing precision. If you're sure that your id values are in `int` range, you probably safe, but I would not go with such assumptions.

What I would do is to investigate possibility to copy that SparseArray class from Android sources and modify it to use `long` keys. I am currently looking at it and at a first glance that is definitely possible.

Comment: The thought had occurred to me.