# Sum of elements of any type

Tags: java

```
public float sum(Object ob) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) {
        sum += ob[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

How can I implement a function that would return the sum of all the array elements of any type?

Comment: Is this homework? Because I'm sure that there's something in the JRE that would handle summing an array for you.

Comment: do you mean a function that takes an array of float arrays, and sums all the elements in all the arrays?

Comment: What is wrong with the one you already have?  What do you want differently?

Comment: The logic is correct. Where are you struck ?

Comment: The method argument type is wrong ;)

Comment: hey no this function should take any array type. Float, int etc and still be able to return the sum how can i do that ?

Comment: @Ignacio - actually, you'd be wrong.  There are no standard methods for summing the elements of arrays ... let alone arrays of different element types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment on the other answer:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to [F

Then it's a `long[]`, not a `float[]`. Just use `long`, not `float` or `Object`. If you declare it explicitly as method argument, then you don't also need to fiddle with casts.

```
public long sum(long[] array) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Primitive Data Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- [The Java Tutorials - Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: should i be overloading methods to accept any array type. But this method would unnecessarily increase code

Comment: Yes, you should. That's the payoff of using primitives. You're however not the only one, they also do it in standard Java SE API. Read this excellent topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337170/managing-highly-repetitive-code-and-documentation-in-java

Answer (score 2):

An educated guess, I havnt done java in a while. Is a cast in order?

**EDIT:** Or, change parameter type to `float[]`:

```
float[] ob = (float[]) ob;
```

---

```
public float sum(Object ob) {
    float sum = 0;
    float[] ob = (float[]) ob;
    for (int i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) {
        sum += ob[i];
    }
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: looks close but i get a exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to [F

Comment: isnt there way to declare the correct type for variable sum beforehand based on the type of array

Comment: Yeah, because the object is not castable to float. Is the object type correct? You sure it isnt an array or arraylist?

Comment: yeah , you can , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject

Comment: well what kind of object is being passed in? is it an array of some sort?

Comment: Try and cast it to an arraylist , its generic

Comment: @Bodman - fail ... won't work ... you can't cast an array to an array list.

Comment: @Stephen C, No you cant cast it , but isnt that a "asList" method of an Array, Im no Java expert.

Comment: @Bodman - Nope.  Arrays.asList works for array types that are assignable to `Object[]` ... and arrays of primitive types are not.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is ... basically ... implement a bad design.  Arrays of primitives in Java are not type compatible, and you cannot do things on them in a polymorphic fashion.

It is not clear what is the best way to fix your design.  But here are a couple of alternatives:

- Write a overloaded methods for each of the cases that make sense; e.g.

  ```
  public int sum(int[] ints) ...

  public long sum(long[] longs) ...

  public float sum(float[] floats) ...
  ```

  Then make sure that you call them on primitive arrays whose type is known at compile time.
- Wrap the arrays in classes, and implement the `sum` method for each of them:

  ```
  public interface NumberArray {
      double sum();
      ...
  }

  public class FloatArray {
      private float[] floats;
      public Float(float[] floats) { this.floats = floats; }
      public double sum() {
          double sum = 0.0D;
          for (float f : floats) { sum += f; }
          return sum;
      }
  }
  ```

  and so on.

It is actually possible to implement a `float sum(Object array)` method ... like this:

```
public float sum(Object obj) {
    float sum = 0;
    if (obj instanceof float[]) {
        for (float f : (float[]) obj) {
            sum += f;
        }
    } else if (obj instanceof int[]) {
        for (int i : (int[]) obj) {
            sum += i;
        }
    } else if ...
    } else {
        throw new SomeException("Can't sum one of these ...");
    }
    return sum;
}
```

but that's non-OO and (IMO) really ugly.  Better to fix the design.